# appharbor test project app.config file does not change its connectionstring

Tags: unit-testing, appharbor

I have a test project in my appharbor solution which uses the connectionstring located in the app.config of the test project.

before appharbor builds the project shouldn't it change the connectionstring in the app.config just like it changes the connectionstring in the Web project?

the connectionstring name is the same in both files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectionstring is only inserted when your code is deployed. In general, you shouldn't hit your database or do other external I/O during unit testing.

Comment: am I right in saying test projects cannot include database interaction? thanks

Comment: You can hard-code the connectionstring if you insist, but that's not a good solution. A better approach is to use databases running in in-memory mode. At AppHarbor, we use sqlite for this. A slightly worse option is to use SQL Server CE, there's a sample here: https://github.com/appharbor/AppHarbor-SQLServerCEUnitTesting-Sample

Comment: thanks friism, Looks like sqlite is the best bet for this. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: If you want to look at RavenDB, it actually has an in memory option basically built in. Big reason why I'm lovin it now.